# mysql update multiple rows from $_POST array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, post

Essentially Im trying to update multiple MySQL rows using an array I got from the `$_POST` variable called "units". Been stuck trying to figure out this. This is what I have so far:

Current Code that doesnt add to the 2nd person:

```
if(isset($_POST['unit'])){ $units .= implode(', ', $_POST['unit']); } else { redirect('addcall.php?err=7'); } 

$my_s = $my->prepare('INSERT INTO `calls`(`call_taker`, `call_time`, `call_type`, `call_priority`, `call_location`, `call_city`, `reporter_name`, `reporter_num`, `call_info`, `units`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)') or die($my->error);
$my_s->bind_param('sssisssiss', $name, $date, $c_type, $c_prio, $c_loc, $c_city, $r_name, $r_num, $c_info, $units) or die($my->error);
$my_s->execute() or die($my->error);
$my_s->close();
$my->close();
$my = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$my_s2 = $my->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `busy` = 1 WHERE `badge` = ? AND `enabled` = 1 AND `confirmed` = 1 AND `duty` = 1') or die($my->error);
$my_s2->bind_param('s', $units) or die($my-error);
$my_s2->execute() or die($my-error);
$my_s2->close();
$my->close();
redirect('dashboard.php');

        <table> // table for checkboxes thats in main HTML area
        <tr> <td>Units Available:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <?php
        $my = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
        $my_s = $my->prepare('SELECT `name`, `badge` FROM `users` WHERE `duty` = 1 AND `busy` = 0');
        $my_s->execute();
        $my_s->store_result();
        if($my_s->num_rows == 0){
            echo "<td>None</td>";
        }
        $my_s->bind_result($u_name, $u_badge);
        while($row = $my_s->fetch()){
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="'.$u_badge.'">'.$u_name.' , #'.$u_badge.'&nbsp</td>'; 
        }
        $my_s->close(); $my->close();?>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Why are you putting `#` on front of the values? If you didn't do that, you could just use the post values as the data to insert into the database.

Comment: Oh so without the # in the value I could just send the post straight data straight in and it would update each user assigned to its 'busy' column?

Comment: Did not change the 2nd users busy column. Only changed the first. Also had to add some heavy checks to it because it was being added to everyone but the 2nd person

Comment: You need a `foreach` loop that updates each badge number separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `foreach` loop to update each badge number in `$_POST['unit']`. Or you can use it to construct a list of values to use in an `IN` test. Unfortunately, you can't bind a parameter to this, so it's necessary to escape them explicitly.

```
if (isset($_POST['unit'])) {
    $units = implode(', ', $_POST['unit']);
    $my_s = $my->prepare('INSERT INTO `calls`(`call_taker`, `call_time`, `call_type`, `call_priority`, `call_location`, `call_city`, `reporter_name`, `reporter_num`, `call_info`, `units`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)') or die($my->error);
    $my_s->bind_param('sssisssiss', $name, $date, $c_type, $c_prio, $c_loc, $c_city, $r_name, $r_num, $c_info, $units) or die($my->error);
    $my_s->execute() or die($my->error);

    $in_units = implode(', ', array_map(function($u) use ($my) { return "'" . $my->real_escape_string($u) . "'"; }, $_POST['unit']));
    $my_s2 = $my->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `busy` = 1 WHERE `badge` IN ($in_units) AND `enabled` = 1 AND `confirmed` = 1 AND `duty` = 1") or die($my->error);
    $my_s2->execute() or die($my-error);
}
```

Comment: Getting this error: 
    Unknown column '$in_units' in 'where clause'

Comment: Fixed, I had the wrong type of quotes so the variable wasn't substituted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your html code is missing a "form" tag. Every type of "input" in html needs to be inside a "form" and "/form" tags that define the method which the form is sent (POST or GET) and what is the destination (what php file), defined by "action" parameter.

Comment: I think he just didn't show that in his code excerpt.

Comment: Yea i left out the rest of the form info since it wasnt relevant. but the form method is POST and action gets sent to the right page